# data.table fifelse giving wrong warning?

Tags: r, data.table, warnings

I found warning difference using `fifelse` from `data.table` library:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.table(ID = rep(1:10,each = 2),x = sample(c(1,NA),20,replace = T))

test1 <- df[,fifelse(any(!is.na(x)),max(x,na.rm = T),as.numeric(NA)),by = ID]
```

produces a warning:

> Warning messages
> 1: In max(x, na.rm = T) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> 2: In max(x, na.rm = T) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

while:

```
test2 <- df[,ifelse(any(!is.na(x)),max(x,na.rm = T),as.numeric(NA)),by = ID]
```

don't. And the two results are identical:

```
identical(test1,test2)
[1] TRUE
```

And there is no -Inf in the result. What does this mean ?

Comment: Just a guess. The error message is coming from the max() function.  I would infer from this, that with fifelse, the function max() is running for all the groups, even when the condition any(!is.na(x)) is FALSE,  while with ifelse it does run only when it is TRUE?

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to use `if/else` as the input is of `length` 1

```
df[, if(any(!is.na(x))) max(x, na.rm = TRUE) else NA_real_, by = ID]
```